# Does the Casimir Effect violate the Quantum Inequalities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, qft-in-curved-spacetime, casimir-effect

Does the [Casimir Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) violate the [Quantum Inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_inequalities)? From what I understand, the Casimir Effect is able to produce negative energy densities for an indefinite amount of time, or is that wrong?

Comment: Did you notice the word unconstrained in the link? I'd say the casimire effect is constrained

Comment: Short answer: No, it does not. You can look at *Lectures on quantum energy inequalities* by Fewster [arXiv:1208.5399](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5399), for application of QI to produce bounds on Casimir energy densities.

Comment: @user23660 OK,i got this. So we can say that Casimir effect is bounded  by Q.I only on the magnitude of the negative energy produced ?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.05610.pdf Alcubierre and Lobo seems to agree that Casimir does violates the QIs, even though no explanation is given.

Answer (score -3):

You are wrong, the Casimir Effect is able to produce negative energy densities for an finite amount of time. So it does not violate the Quantum Inequalities.

Comment: I know than Casimir effect have constraints on the magnitude of the negative energy produced but i don't understand why are you saying that it can do this only for a finite amount of time..For what i read you need to separate the plates from each other to stop the attraction between them (negative energy) but maybe i completely misunderstood the subject.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little more? As currently written, it seems to be a conclusory statement with no explanation. Alternatively, if this is meant as more of a comment than an answer, it should be posted as a comment not as an answer. (Once you have sufficient rep you will be able to post comments.)